# Debian 9.4 (stretch) change UART4 baud rate to 9600

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, beagleboneblack, debian-stretch

I researched and tried a lot updating uart4 baud rate of Beaglebone green running Debian 9.4, but could not succeed. I am not even sure whether uart4 is enabled in Debian 9.4.
As per am335x-boneblack.dts, uart4 is disabled and clock-frequency value is 0x2dc6c00 (this is for baudrate 115200 I guess).

```
serial@481a6000 {
    compatible = "ti,am3352-uart", "ti,omap3-uart";
    ti,hwmods = "uart4";
    clock-frequency = <0x2dc6c00>;
    reg = <0x481a6000 0x2000>;
    interrupts = <0x2c>;
    status = "disabled";
    linux,phandle = <0xa7>;
    phandle = <0xa7>;
    };
```

Comment: Baudrate should be set directly in software when configuring serial port. What does "ls -l /dev/ttyO*" shows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [termios library](https://linux.die.net/man/3/termios) for uart configuration in linux. The termios functions describe a general terminal interface that is provided to control asynchronous communications ports. Here is an [example](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Serial_Programming/termios) of usage in c.